# Regex - Does not contain certain characters except for end

Tags: .net, regex

I need to match any lines that end with "&" but does not contain "," or "&" in between.

```
a b c &

a, b, c, &

a & b, c &

a & b
```

I was able to get partial success by using:

```
^(?!.*,).*&.*$
```

and I got both:

```
a b c &
a & b
```

So I've tried it with

```
^(?!.*(,|&)).*&.*$
```

And I'm unable to get any matches. How can I modify my regex so I can only get `a b c &`?  I am using .NET

Comment: Maybe `(?m)^(?!.*(?:,|&(?!\r?$))).*&\r?$`? Or [`^.*(?<![&,].*)&\r?$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e.*%28%3f%3c!%5b%26%2c%5d.*%29%26%5cr%3f%24&i=a+b+c+%26%0d%0aa%2c+b%2c+c%2c+%26%0d%0aa+%26+b%2c+c+%26%0d%0aa+%26+b&o=m)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you should get what you need by using a negated character class, e.g.

```
^[^,&]*&\s*$
```

using the multiline flag.

You can replace `\s*` by `\r?` if you don't want to allow trailing spaces as suggested by revo.

You might also want to add the newline character to the negated character class (`[^,&\n]`) if you are working with multiline text (instead of testing line for line) to avoid overlapping matches.

Comment: It would be better to use `\r?` instead of `\s*` otherwise spaces too are allowed at the end of line.

Comment: @revo sure, aded a note.

Comment: I think OP processes a multiline input, thus, you'd better add a newline char into the negated character class. Actually, that is the point of `\r?` before `$` in a .NET regex that is compiled with `RegexOptions.Multiline` option.